# Partition Hard Drive For Data

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, hard-drive

Greetings ~ I am a new Linux/Ubuntu user. For various reasons (mostly my own ignorance) I am on my third install of Ubuntu 12.04. I want to partition the hard drive to create a drive for data and personal files *in case* I ever have to install again. I have been struggling all afternoon to make a gparted live USB. Tuxboot looked like the answer but I get an error message when using it. So, I am asking for help. Ultimately, I want to partition the hard drive for data and personal files. What do you recommend?

Comment: Please provide us more info about the error message, and how is your disk partitioned now (for example, is Ubuntu using all the HDD space?)

Comment: Now Tuxboot is doing nothing. It looks like to starts to "process files" then it disappears

Comment: You've probably made some mistakes while installing it on the USB, try following the guide I linked into the answer or use the Ubuntu liveCD and you should have no problem. If you still have problems booting from USB, try using another "method". Try using UNetbootin instead, or the "manual method" using dd (be careful to select the proper USB flash device) as wrote into the guide. (guide link: http://gparted.sourceforge.net/liveusb.php )

Answer (score 1):

If your Ubuntu install is not using all your HDD space you can make a partition using the free space. If you used all the space for Ubuntu, you have to use a liveCD to partition the hard drive, because you can not resize an in use partition.

A good and free partition editor is `GParted`, you can either use its liveCD and follow this guide to install it on USB: http://gparted.sourceforge.net/liveusb.php or use the Ubuntu live environment in which you will find `GParted` already installed and ready to be used. 
So, if you have any trouble with the `GParted` live you can use the Ubuntu live as well!

After you start `GParted`, here you can find a nice guide to use it: http://gparted.sourceforge.net/display-doc.php?name=help-manual
Anyway, re-sizing a partition is very easy:

1. Right click -> Resize/Move
2. Resize it using the "slider" (be careful: do not move the partition, just resize it!)

After the resize, you will have to make a new partition for data:

1. Select the unallocated space on the disk device
2. Right click -> New

Now check all the modification you made and confirm them by clicking the "tick" or Modify->Apply

Now you can reboot. Remember that this partition won't be auto-mounted at the startup, in order to do this you have to modify the `fstab` file. This may help you: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab

P.S.: Reading this article may help you during the resize operation: http://www.howtogeek.com/114503/how-to-resize-your-ubuntu-partitions/

Comment: Thank you for all the information. Your first two links are the instructions that I have been trying to follow. OK, now I see that I can use Gparted from the Ubuntu Live USB. Will try that.

Comment: yes,you can try that.